# How do I get output or error stream for jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to connect DB2 via JDBC. How do I get the output message that sql would have returned as like IDE. 
E.g Select query would return 100 rows were fetched.
Insert would return the number of rows updated.

Also the error messages like no rows found, User does not have privilege to access database, Insert could not be performed due to duplicate primary key etc.

Comment: For the errors part, the message is probably in a `SqlException` that is thrown.

Comment: I believe a JDBC `executeUpdate` would return the number of rows affected.  As for error messages, just catch the exception and check it.

Comment: Yes but how do I catch the number of rows affected in a String? May be I can look into SqlException to get the error messages for those which went for exception. 
But I want to get the output stream also for the queries that did not go for exception. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`catch` the exception thrown and print the stack trace.

```
try{
    // your SQL work
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will print the error in your output console.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JDBC api `execute update` to get the changed row count. And the exceptions to get other messages.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)

> **int executeUpdate(String sql) throws SQLException**
>
> Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or
> DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an
> SQL DDL statement. Note:This method cannot be called on a
> PreparedStatement or CallableStatement.
>
> Parameters: sql - an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement,
> such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns
> nothing, such as a DDL statement.
>
> **Returns: either the row count
> for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL
> statements that return nothing**
>
> Throws: SQLException - if a database
> access error occurs, this method is called on a closed Statement, the
> given SQL statement produces a ResultSet object, the method is called
> on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement SQLTimeoutException - when
> the driver has determined that the timeout value that was specified by
> the setQueryTimeout method has been exceeded and has at least
> attempted to cancel the currently running Statement